# Recover multiple Microsoft Edge windows with its tabs

Tags: microsoft-edge, session-restore

I had two Edge windows opened, one window with multiple tabs and the other window with just one tab. I closed both windows but accidentally closed the window with multiple tabs first. When I launched Edge again it of course recovered the window with just the one tab.

I looked under `%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Recovery\Active` and there I have five files:

`{820DDAAF-D3A5-11E6-BF12...}.dat 2017-01-06 01:17`
`{8FE2C0FF-D3A5-11E6-BF12...}.dat 2017-01-06 01:18`
`{45ED77A0-0582-11E7-BF20...}.dat 2017-03-10 12:11 (today)`
`{F19EC8A8-04CE-11E7-BF20...}.dat 2017-03-10 12:15 (today)`
`RecoveryStore.{376FBBD8-...}.dat 2017-03-10 13:08 (today)`

The closing of the windows occurred 12:11 or 12:15, I don’t know exactly.
I still have the window with one tab opened, I don’t dare to close it.
The RecoveryStore…dat file keeps updating.
I can’t copy the last three files since they are being used.

Is it possible to recover the session previous the one that is currently restored?